# Nested wherehas with different relation in Eloquent

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is some relation between Eloquent classes in a Laravel 5 application:

- `B` belongs to `A`
- `B` has one `C`

Table are built with the correct foreign keys.
Here is a scope method of `A`:

```
public function scopeMyScope(Builder $query) 
{
    return $query->whereHas('B.C', function($q) {
        $q->whereRaw("1=1");
    });
}
```

If we call `A::myScope()->get()`, it results in an SQL error, because laravel built this query:

```
select * from "a" where (select count(*) from "b" where "a"."a.b_id" = "b"."id" and (select count(*) from "c" where "c"."b_id" = "b"."id" and 1=1) >=1 ) >= 1
```

The error is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column c.b_id does not exist
```

So, the query built is wrong because there is no `c.b_id` column (because `B hasOne C`, so the join column is in `C`). Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in laravel's query builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can understand, you need to do a nested whereHas, so:

```
public function scopeMyScope(Builder $query)
{
    // b is the name of the relationship...
    return $query->whereHas('b', function($q)
    {
         // c is the name of the relationship...
         $q->whereHas('c', function()
         {
             $q->where(1, 1);
         });
    }
}
```

Does this solve your problem?